# iPad Pro Simulator not displaying layer.mask

Tags: swift, ipad, ios-simulator, calayer, mask

I have tested the following code on all simulators and it works fine except on the iPad Pro. On the the iPad Pro is does not display. The gradient layer will work fine, it is only when I try and apply a mask that it will not appear on the iPad Pro Simulator:

```
func createOverlay()
{
    if !(gradientLayer != nil)
    {
        self.gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    print(gradientLayer.frame)
    gradientLayer.colors = [appColour.CGColor, appColourDark.CGColor]

    //--------FROM HERE ON DOES NOT WORK ON IPAD PRO, NO CRASH BUT LAYER DOES NOT APPEAR
    self.alpha = maskAlpha

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: xOffset - offset, y: yOffset - offset, width: circleWidth + (offset * 2), height: circleHeight + (offset * 2))
    let bPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))
    CGPathAddPath(path, nil, bPath.CGPath)

    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    maskLayer.path = path
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

I am hoping this is just a simulator issue but if you see something in my code that might be causing a problem please let me know.

I have tried replacing the gradient layer with a normal layer but it still does not display.

Here is full code, it is a custom sub-class of UIView and is the top layer of a view controller setup in IB:

```
import UIKit

protocol TipSpeechDelegate
{
    func stopSpeaking()
}

@IBDesignable

class HoleMaskView: UIView
{
var xOffset : CGFloat = 0.0
var yOffset : CGFloat = 0.0

var circleWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
var circleHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

var maskAlpha: CGFloat = 0.9

var offset: CGFloat = 10.0
var inset: CGFloat = 8.0

var tipText: String = ""

var myLabel: UILabel?

var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!

var relativeCorner: RelativeCornerType = RelativeCornerType.upperLeftCorner

var delegate: TipSpeechDelegate!


override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{        
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HoleMaskView.handleTap(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}


func drawTipText()
{
    createOverlay()

    let height: CGFloat = self.frame.size.height

    if (self.myLabel != nil)
    {
        myLabel?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    if (yOffset < height/2)
    {
        self.myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: inset, y: (yOffset + circleHeight), width: self.frame.width-(inset*2), height: self.frame.height-(yOffset + circleHeight)))
    }
    else
    {
        self.myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: inset, y: 0, width: self.frame.width-(inset*2), height: yOffset))
    }

    self.myLabel?.text = tipText
    self.myLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.myLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 20.0)
    self.myLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    self.myLabel?.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    self.myLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.myLabel?.setNeedsLayout()
    self.addSubview(myLabel!)
}


func updateTipText(text: String, circle: CGRect)
{
    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = circle.origin.y
    xOffset = circle.origin.x
    circleWidth = circle.size.width
    circleHeight = circle.size.height

    self.drawTipText()
}


func tipText(text: String, rFrame: CGRect, inView: UIView) -> Bool
{
    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = inView.convertPoint(rFrame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = rFrame.size.width
    circleHeight = rFrame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}


func tipText(text: String, button: UIButton) -> Bool
{
    if button.hidden
    {
        return false
    }

    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = button.superview!.convertPoint(button.frame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = button.frame.size.width
    circleHeight = button.frame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}

func tipText(text: String, label: UILabel) -> Bool
{
    if label.hidden
    {
        return false
    }

    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = label.superview!.convertPoint(label.frame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = label.frame.size.width
    circleHeight = label.frame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}

func tipText(text: String, textView: UITextView) -> Bool
{
    if textView.hidden
    {
        return false
    }

    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = textView.superview!.convertPoint(textView.frame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    circleHeight = textView.frame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}



func tipText(text: String) -> Bool
{
    showTipMask()

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = 0.0
    xOffset = self.frame.size.width/2
    circleWidth = 0.0
    circleHeight = 0.0

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}


func tipText(text: String, view: UIView) -> Bool
{
    if view.hidden
    {
        return false
    }

    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = view.superview!.convertPoint(view.frame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = view.frame.size.width
    circleHeight = view.frame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}


func tipText(text: String, stepper: UIStepper) -> Bool
{
    if stepper.hidden
    {
        return false
    }

    showTipMask()

    let convertedPoint = stepper.superview!.convertPoint(stepper.frame.origin, toView: self)

    self.tipText = text
    yOffset = convertedPoint.y
    xOffset = convertedPoint.x
    circleWidth = stepper.frame.size.width
    circleHeight = stepper.frame.size.height

    self.drawTipText()

    return true
}


func showTipMask()
{
    self.alpha = alphaHide
    self.hidden = false

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:
        {
            self.alpha = alphaShow
        }
    )
}


func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if delegate != nil
    {
        delegate.stopSpeaking()
    }
    print("tapped internal")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations:
        {
            () -> Void in
            self.alpha = alphaHide
        },
                completion:
        {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            self.hidden = true
        }
    )
}


func createOverlay()
{
    if !(gradientLayer != nil)
    {
        self.gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    print(gradientLayer.frame)
    gradientLayer.colors = [appColour.CGColor, appColourDark.CGColor]

    self.alpha = maskAlpha

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: xOffset - offset, y: yOffset - offset, width: circleWidth + (offset * 2), height: circleHeight + (offset * 2))
    let bPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))
    CGPathAddPath(path, nil, bPath.CGPath)

    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    maskLayer.path = path
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
}
```

Thanks

Greg

Comment: where do you call `createOverlay()`?

Comment: I added the class so you can see how it is called

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Currently I scale it down to 50%, then the graph appears correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. 
Currently I

- turn on the Debug -> Optimize Rendering for Window Scale
- scale it down to 50%

then the graph appears correctly.

But one of my colleges told me that he has to turn off the ORWS option. Wired.